# Odroidh2 Debian - Unable to ping network gateway / no network connectivity

Tags: linux, networking, routes, ping, connectivity

I have an OdroidH2 with docker setup.

It was working fine for a few months and suddenly, out of nowhere it stopped having any internet/intranet connectivity.

It's connectivity is going through an Ethernet cable, not WiFi and the interface that is supposed to have the connection is enp3s0 with an ip address of 192.168.1.100.

I have performed the following troubleshooting steps:

- Restart (of course, always the first step)
- Checked interface settings via `ifconfig` and also in /etc/network/interfaces
- Checked the routing via `route -n`
- Checked iptables (iptables was populated with the docker configuration, I've flushed the iptables including nat and mangle and set the default policy to ACCEPT for input, forward and output. Restarted the networking service afterwards)
- Checked if it was able to ping itself and the default gateway (it is able to ping itself but not the gateway, or any other devices)
- Checked if another device was able to ping the OdroidH2 (host unreachable)
- Checked `dmesg` and for some reason, I had 2 firmwares that were not able to be loaded (already installed and rebooted after installation):

  - rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw (after checking, this is the firmware for the network interfaces)
  - i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin (didn't research much about this one, something to do with runtime power management??)

After all of these steps, I still am unable to get the network connectivity going.

Below you can find information regarding my current configuration:

### dmesg output

Stackoverflow does not allow me to put all the information from my dmesg output so I had to put it on google drive: [dmesg_output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Izuxbgt_9E7aREcwBq4_hemlLgaIAxB5)

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.100   dc1 dc1.samdom.andrewoliverhome.local   samdom.andrewoliverhome.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

### `iptables -nvL` output (after clearing and reloading the networking service)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

### /etc/resolv.conf

```
#nameserver 127.0.0.1
#nameserver 8.8.8.8
#nameserver 8.8.4.4
search samdom.andrewoliverhome.local
#domain samdom.andrewoliverhome.local
nameserver 192.168.1.100
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

### `route -n` output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-debc10cb5b21
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
```

### /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo enp2s0 enp3s0
#auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug enp2s0 enp3s0

#iface enp2s0 inet manual
#   post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface

#iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
#   broadcast 169.254.99.255
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254


#iface enp2s0 inet manual
#iface enp3s0 inet manual

#iface br0 inet static
#   bridge_ports enp2s0 enp3s0
#       address 192.168.1.100
#       broadcast 192.168.1.255
#       netmask 255.255.255.0
#       gateway 192.168.1.254
#
```

In /etc/resolv.conf, the reason I have the primary nameserver to be itself is because I am running a docker container that is serving as a samba-ad-dc.
In order for OdroidH2 to find all of my devices in the domain, it needs to make dns queries to the samba dc, if samba is not able to find a dns record, it will autoforward it to 8.8.8.8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the troubleshooting done, the issue is not within the OdroidH2 itself, it was with my router.

The LAN port that I'm using malfunctioned. I switched the Ethernet cable to a different LAN port and it worked.